# Looking for a Geotiff image browser and labelling tool

Tags: image-viewer, deep-learning

We have large sets of classified satellite image tiles to train a convolutional neural network and looking for a tool to browse our dataset mainly for visual quality checks, ideally with an option to delete images that are identified as not being suitable. Beside browsing the dataset, being able to (re-)label images would be a plus.

Our images are in GeoTIFF format (georeferenced TIFFs), so most image viewers are not able to display them. GIS software is also not really a useful option, because it is not build for this kind of task.

Do you know any good desktop (MacOS / Windows) or a web-based application for this purpose?

Comment: I assume the GeoTIFF files use the tiled TIFF format because of their size. Support for tiled tiff images is pretty rare so this might be the problem why you have not found an image viewer. What viewers have you already tested?

Comment: So far, we converted the GeoTiff files to JPEG and created a small webapp to display the images in a web browser. Apparently IrfanView (Windows only) is able to display GeoTiff images, so this would be an option. A few browsers also have native Tiff-Support (I wasn't aware): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support